# How to Open and edit file outside eclipse workspace, while having the file in sync with Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am opening and editing a file (in my Eclipse plugin), in the filesystem by using `java.io.File`. But everytime i edit it, the **Eclipse is out of sync with that resource**! So after my code edits it, if user tries to operate on it in the UI, Eclipse says resource out of sync! I know refreshing the file in UI will work but everytime doing that will be annoying!

Is there any way to open the resource in such a way that eclipse is in sync with the file?

refreshLocal API is not useful for me!!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Preferences > General > Workspace` and select the `Refresh using native hooks or polling` check box.

Comment: can i do something without the preferences? I need a piece of code to do this! Any idea?

Comment: If you are doing this in a plug-in you should use the `IFile` interfaces to create files or use `refreshLocal` immediately after the files are created.

Answer (score 0):

The [Filesync plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/filesync#.UoHvR-ISX9Y) worked fine for me. It is [configurable](http://www.onehippo.org/7_7/library/development/use-filesync-eclipse-plugin-for-faster-turn-around.html). No manual refreshing needed.

Comment: can i do something without plugin? I need a piece of code to do this! Any idea?

Comment: @Destructor I'm sorry, but I am not familar enough with the eclipse API. You can however take a look into the source of the plugin : http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/filesync4eclipse/source/browse/#git%2FFileSync%2Fsrc%2Fde%2Floskutov%2Ffs%253Fstate%253Dclosed and then perhaps contact the original author.